# Find previous item by key value in vector of maps

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have a vector of maps like this:

```
[{:id 2 :val "v1"} {:id 5 :val "v2"} {:id 10 :val "v3"}]
```

and now I want to find an element previous to chosen id.
For example: when provided with id = 10 i want to receive:

```
{:id 5 :val "v2"}
```

and when selected id = 2 then return nil.

I'm new in clojurescript programming and cannot think of simple solution for this problem... Help please :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `partition` to pair adjacent maps and then search for a match on the second by id:

```
(def ms [{:id 2 :val "v1"} {:id 5 :val "v2"} {:id 10 :val "v3"}])
(ffirst (filter #(= 10 (:id (second %))) (partition 2 1 ms)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`(partition 2 1 data)` in the accepted answer is an option, but here are two alternatives based on a "lagged" sequence.

This one first constructs the look-up table (mapping next ids to each item), which should be more performant if many lookups needs to be done. You could even easily `map` over it. But this approach requires ids to be unique.

```
(let [data [{:id 2 :val "v1"} {:id 5 :val "v2"} {:id 10 :val "v3"}]
      ids  (zipmap (map :id (rest data)) data)]
  [(ids 10)
   ids])
; [{:id 5, :val "v2"}
;  {5 {:id 2, :val "v1"}, 10 {:id 5, :val "v2"}}]
```

This second one generates a sequence of matching documents, which is necessary if there might be more than one:

```
(let [data     [{:id 2 :val "v1"} {:id 5 :val "v2"} {:id 10 :val "v3"}]
      next-ids (->> data rest (map :id))]
  (->>
    (map (fn [item next-id] (if (= 10 next-id) item))
      data next-ids)
    (filter some?)
    first))
; {:id 5, :val "v2"}
```

You'd get similar code by using `partition` but instead of `#(...)` you'd use destructuring: `(fn [first-item second-item] (= 10 (:id second-item)))`. Indeed [ffirst](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ffirst) comes very handy in this approach.